# Unable to install gcloud SDK on Windows 10

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install Google Cloud SDK by running the executable file from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart)

It doesn't give any error or sth but it's always stuck there.

I left it to complete the installation for a night, still no increment though.

[image]

I canceled and tried again but the result is same.
How can I install it on Windows 10? Do you have any other ideas?

As suggested in the comments, I am sharing installer logs:

```
2021-08-23 11:05:50,749 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components']
2021-08-23 11:05:50,764 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components', 'update']
2021-08-23 11:05:50,764 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.components.update] with arguments: [--allow-no-backup: "True", --quiet: "True", COMPONENT-IDS:5: "['anthoscli', 'bq', 'gcloud', 'gsutil', 'powershell']"]
2021-08-23 11:05:50,764 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Beginning update. This process may take several minutes.

2021-08-23 11:05:50,873 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dl.google.com:443
2021-08-23 11:05:51,049 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool https://dl.google.com:443 "GET /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json HTTP/1.1" 200 159482
2021-08-23 11:05:51,203 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,203 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 
Your current Cloud SDK version is: 353.0.0

2021-08-23 11:05:51,203 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Installing components from version: 353.0.0

2021-08-23 11:05:51,203 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |                     These components will be installed.                     |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ +-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |                         Name                        |  Version   |   Size   |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ +-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ BigQuery Command Line Tool                         
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___     2.0.71
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  < 1 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)     
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___     2.0.67
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  < 1 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific)       
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 2021.04.30
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  < 1 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                    
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___       4.66
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  4.3 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___       4.63
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  < 1 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Cloud Tools for PowerShell                         
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___   1.0.1.10
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 17.9 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Windows command line ssh tools                     
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___           
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  3.2 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ anthoscli                                          
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___     0.2.17
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 47.3 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ gcloud cli dependencies                            
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 2021.04.16
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ | 
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  < 1 MiB
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___  
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ |
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ +-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2021-08-23 11:05:51,219 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dl.google.com:443
2021-08-23 11:05:51,381 DEBUG    urllib3.connectionpool https://dl.google.com:443 "GET /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/RELEASE_NOTES HTTP/1.1" 200 682729
2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ For the latest full release notes, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes


2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ #============================================================#

2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ #= Creating update staging area                             =#

2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ #
2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ======
2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ======
2021-08-23 11:05:51,705 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ======
2021-08-23 11:05:54,161 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:05:56,971 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:05:59,846 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:02,082 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:04,303 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:06,110 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:09,156 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:11,241 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:16,782 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:19,362 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:22,122 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:24,664 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:27,367 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:29,862 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:32,386 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:35,601 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:38,911 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:43,196 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:47,927 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:52,423 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:56,298 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:06:59,090 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:03,401 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:06,934 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:11,363 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:15,105 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:18,830 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:20,289 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:22,028 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:23,481 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:24,898 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:26,042 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:27,184 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:28,341 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:30,975 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:36,676 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
2021-08-23 11:07:40,160 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ =
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if you can find the installer logs in `C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\DATE` and share them in the question? (Remember to redact any private info)

Comment: @mgoya Thanks for the tip. I added the logs into the question.

Comment: I created this [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/197942009) for this situation, please add any extra information you have there so it can be investigated by the Cloud SDK specialist team.